# MySQL Find first and last rows of rows with matching values in the same column

Tags: mysql, group-by, match, return-value, multiple-columns

Sorry for the bad wording on the question, it's hard to explain exactly what I need.

I used this query:

```
select * 
from table 
where unique_id in (
  select unique_id from table group by unique_id having count(*) > 1
)
```

Which gives me a result like the following:

```
id    date         unique_id
12    3/3/2013     asdf1
13    3/4/2013     asdf1
14    3/5/2013     asdf1
15    3/6/2013     asdf1
16    3/8/2013     qwer2
17    3/9/2013     qwer2
18    3/10/2013    qwer2
19    3/11/2013    zxcv3
20    3/12/2013    zxcv3
21    2/2/2012     jkl
22    2/3/2012     jkl
22    2/4/2012     jkl
23    2/5/2012     jkl
24    2/5/2012     jkl
25    2/6/2012     jkl
26    2/7/2012     jkl
```

I'd like the query to further refine those results and leave me the first and last row of each set of matching unique_id's

** in each set of matching unique_id's, the results will always follow the pattern of ID + 1 and date + 1 day.
**  There are no records where this condition having count(*) > 1 will be equal to 1.

So in other words I'd like the query to return only:

```
12 3/3/2013  asdf1
15 3/6/2013  asdf1
16 3/8/2013  qwer2
18 3/10/2013 qwer2
19 3/11/2013 zxcv3
20 3/12/2013 zxcv3
21 2/2/2012 jkl
26 2/7/2012 jkl
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a dump of the table your using?

Comment: Hey, what information from the table do you need specifically?  The real table contains sensitive information, but when I run that query on it, the results are identical to what I posted there.

Comment: Can your table have a date pair for a unique_id where the ID column of the later date is smaller than the ID column of the earlier date?

Comment: No, it will always* follow the pattern I posted.  ID + 1 date + 1 day and the same unique_id until there is a new unique_id.

Comment: just would be easier to just import a dump... nevermind, Declan already solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the sequencing of hte ID and date columns match, you can use the following.

```
SELECT  id
        ,date
        ,unique_id
FROM    (
        SELECT  min(id) as id
                ,min(date) as date
                ,unique_id
                ,count(id) as rec_count
        from    table
        group by
                unique_id
        union
        SELECT  max(id) as id
                ,max(date) as date
                ,unique_id
                ,count(id) as rec_count
        from    table
        group by
                unique_id
        ) SQ
WHERE   SQ.rec_count > 1
```

Comment: Sorry, typo in the post (which I have now corrected).  Change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE   SQ.rec_count > 1`.

Comment: Hey, if you are still around, how could I even further refine the query to return results like this:  3/3/2013 - 3/6/2013  asdf1  and the next row 3/8/2013 - 3/10/2013 qwer2